# Biometric-security lock-screen?

Tags: security, lock-screens

Is there a way to apply a biometric lock (as in, a look screen) to an Android device? e.g. the unlocker has to pass a fingerprint / retina / voice scan. I've read about startup companies and general ideas, but haven't seen any actual product.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out [unlock via face recognition will be built-in in Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich](http://www.engadget.com/2011/10/18/android-ice-cream-sandwich-adds-face-unlock-feature/).

Answer (score 2):

Some phones have hardware built in for such things. For example, my Motorola Atrix has a fingerprint scanner to unlock it, http://www.authentec.com/a/ATRIXFAQs.aspx. Also, like you pointed out, Ice Cream Sandwich is going to have facial recognition for locking/unlocking.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to develop one, but we don't have pixel-per-pixel touch screens(like the one that the second generation Microsoft Surface uses) on our Android phones, so it will not be accurate, nor even trustable. What may be out on the Market are lock screens that imitate those systems, but they are just for visual effects.

The only example that is valid is the face-recognition, the iris-recognition I don't know, but I think this needs a lot more improved technology. You can check out [BioLock To Bring Biometric Security (Iris Scanner, Facial Recognition) To Android](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-applications/68187-biolock-bring-biometric-security-iris-scanner-facial-recognition-android.html) for more information.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "pixel-per-pixel" touchscreens... and in any case, I'm guessing (1) fingerprint scan requires the camera - the touchscreen isn't appropriate for that, (2) voice requires the microphone, and (3) retina requires a higher-quality camera than what any phone currently has. Still, I'm asking about any biometric product from a consumer standpoint, I'm less concerned with the specific technique used to achieve it.

Comment: Touchscreens like the one that they introduced on the second generation of the Microsoft Surface. More information about it just watch their keynote at CES 2011: http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/events/ces/

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using an app in beta called Zwypelock. This app learns your unique behavior — the way you hold you phone, the pressure you apply to your touch screen, etc. It lets you unlock the phone with just a swipe.

Here is the link

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zighra.zwypelockss&hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, dedutt! Could you also provide a link where to find Zwypelock ([edit]ing it into your question would be best)?